# shinyapps.io and github Packages

Tags: r, github, shiny

I have a shiny program in R that works great.  But I am having trouble deploying it to shinyapps.io.

The javascript error console gives me the following error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:46574
  Downloading github repo jlisic/saAlloc@master
  Installing saAlloc
  '/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpvmoFM3/devtools2c6b564aad/jlisic-saAlloc-62692fc'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
Error : Command failed (1)
```

There is nothing fancy about my package it just has a default Makevars file.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is you package on github public?

Comment: yes https://github.com/jlisic/saAlloc

Comment: This issue still exists and it's extremely problematic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have also been struggling with this issue, and I just found a working answer in the shinyapps.io Google users group by @Yihui. Quoting his post:

> You should not install the package inside your app (i.e. do not call
>   `install_github()` in your app code). Just install it locally, and
>   shinyapps.io will figure out how to install it on the server.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shinyapps-users/5S8jTJ-SeHM/HCPGUjYVUM4J

Removing the `devtools::install_github()` line in `server.R` worked for me. Back end magic!

EDIT: The reason why this works is explained in more detail in this `rsconnect` issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/88

Comment: I want to add that installing a local clone of the package with `R CMD INSTALL` did not work for me. I really had to install my own package with `remotes::install_github()` for the shinyapps.io deployment